# How to use $resource in Angular to work with a RESTful api

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I'm trying to add some basic CRUD functionality to MEAN stack. I've created a RESTful service that works and I'm confused about how to wire it all up. I can get it to work, but I want to make sure I'm doing things the best way and not creating an unnecessary hack.

My api route for a single Person is like this:

```
// Find one person
app.get('/api/person/:id', function(req, res) {
  Person.find ( {_id: req.params.id },
    function(err, data){
      res.json(data);
    }
  )});

 // Find group of people
 app.get('/api/person', function(req, res) {
   // use mongoose to get all people in the database
   Person.find(function(err, data) {
     res.json(data); 
 });
```

This seems to work in that if I go to a URI with an ID, as in localhost://3000/api/person/23423434, I see JSON data like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "532d8a97e443e72ef3cb3e60",
    "firstname": "Horace",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "age": 33
  }
]
```

This tells me the basic mechanics of my RESTful api are working. Now I'd like to display that data with angular in a template like so:

```
<h3>{{ person.firstname + ' ' + person.lastname }} </h3>
```

To do that, I just need to create a $scope.person object with get() or query(). Here's the relevant part of my app:

```
angular.module('crudApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/api/person/:id',
        {
          templateUrl: 'partials/person.html',
          controller: 'PersonCtrl'
        });
      }])
      .factory('Person', function($resource){
        return $resource('api/person/:id', { id: '@_id'});
      })
      .controller('PersonCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, Person){
         $scope.person = Person.get( { id: $routeParams.id } ); // Having trouble here!
      });
```

The trouble I'm having is that get() fails with an error (Error: [$resource:badcfg]). On the other hand, if I use Person.query(), I get back an array, which means I need to change my template to the following:

```
<h3>{{ person[0].firstname + ' ' + person[0].lastname }} </h3>
```

This works, but seems strange and isn't like what I've seen in angular tutorials. The only other solution I've found is to set $scope.person in a callback:

```
Person.query({ id: $routeParams.id  }, function(person){
  $scope.person = person[0];
});
```

This works with my original unmodified template. Is it the best or right way to work with RESTful apis like this? Is there a better way?

Answer: the answer is in comment below. My problem is that api is using Person.find() but should be using Person.findOne( { _id: req.params.id }); Using findOne() returns a single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your api should look like this:

```
route -> '/api/person/:id'
    return single person
route -> '/api/person'
    return array of persons
```

then if you want to get by id, you shall use `get` method, or if you want to get all persons, you should use `query` method. Your mistake is that you shall return single object when getting by id

Comment: Actually, I think that is what I'm doing. My api has a route   // Find one person
  app.get('/api/person/:id', function(req, res) {
    Person.find ( {_id: req.params.id },
      function(err, contact){
        res.json(contact);
      }
    )
  });

Comment: @adamKiryk No, use `findOne` instead of `find`. `find` returns array, `findOne` returns single object